# Forcing an export name for Visual Studio C++ static library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have trouble linking a static library that is made out of a few cpp files in a project that is "pure" C .c files. The .c file is looking for a function object with  syntax _FUNCTIONAME, like this:

```
logforwarder.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _getEventLogProviders
```

but the .lib file exports it like this:
Dump of file M:...\Release\recvevent.lib

```
File Type: LIBRARY

     Exports

       ordinal    name

                  ?_getEventLogProviders@@YAIPAPAD@Z (unsigned int __cdecl _getE
ventLogProviders(char * *))

  Summary

          C3 .debug$S
          14 .idata$2
          14 .idata$3
           4 .idata$4
           4 .idata$5
           C .idata$6
```

My exports.def file looks like this:

```
EXPORTS
 getEventLogProviders=getEventLogProviders @4
```

A library the project can link successfully, exports the functions like this:

```
Dump of file M:\...\screenshot.lib

File Type: LIBRARY

     Exports

       ordinal    name

                  _ReflectiveLoader@4
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  decoration adds both the underscore at the beginning of the exported function and the @ with the number at the end. Your `.def` file should therefore look like this:

```
getEventLogProviders=_getEventLogProviders@4
```

As it is now, the `.def` doesn't have any effect, as the mangled function is not written correctly.

Comment: Almost there, now dumpbin gives me:  "getEventLogProviders" as function name while linked still searches for "_getEventLogProviders".

Comment: The line that worked: "_getEventLogProviders=_getEventLogProviders@4"

Comment: That's another bug.  The program that uses the export is not using the correct calling convention.  It uses __cdecl instead of __stdcall.  That's going to imbalance the stack at runtime, very hard to diagnose.

Comment: That's _not_ another bug. It's the same bug. The @4 is the [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C_name_decoration_in_Microsoft_Windows) of stdcall, and the .def file is the cast to shut up the compiler.